# Select earliest and latest dates from two rows and return a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this result set:

```
Title                                CourseEventKey CourseKey   StartDate               EndDate
------------------------------------ -------------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
Branch Summit 2012 - Power of Team   32             657         2012-05-22 08:00:00.000 2012-05-22 17:00:00.000
Branch Summit 2012 - Power of Team   32             657         2012-05-23 08:00:00.000 2012-05-23 17:00:00.000
```

As you can see, these rows have duplicate values in every column except for `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

I need this result set to contain only distinct values in  `CourseEventKey` by calculating the earliest `StartDate` and latest `EndDate` and selecting the resulting values into their corresponding columns.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easily done with a group by.

```
 SELECT name, MAX(enddate), MIN(startdate) FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT Title, CourseEventKey, CourseKey, MIN( StartDate), MAX(StartDate)
 FROM Table
 GROUP BY Title, CourseEventKey, CourseKey
```